# sharpziplib - can you add a file without it copying the entire zip first?

Tags: c#, performance, sharpziplib

Im trying to add a file to an existing .zip file using sharpziplib - problem is, the zip file is 1GB in size.  When i try to add 1 small file (400k) sharpziplib creates a copy/temp of the orig zip file before adding the new file - this poses a problem when the amount of free disk space is less than 2x the zip file you are trying to update.

for example:
1GB zip myfile.zip
1GB zip myfile.zip.tmp.293

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(path);
zf.BeginUpdate();
zf.Add(file);   // Adding a 400k file here causes a 1GB temp file to be created
zf.EndUpdate();
zf.Close();
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:

http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/5934/17056.aspx#17056

> Hi,
>
> If you are creating a new Zip archive
>   is might be easier to use the
>   ZipOutputStream class instead.
>
> If you are updating you can get the
>   ZipFile class to write directly to the
>   existing archive on disk if you
>   choose.  IArchiveStorage (The library
>   supplies a DiskArchiveStorage) is the
>   key interface passed when BeginUpdate
>   is called.  It has a UpdateMode
>   property which can be set to Safe or
>   Direct.
>
> The implications are obvious
>   hopefully.  Failure during an update
>   may corrupt the archive losing the
>   data.
>
> hth, -jr-

Comment: Would be good to quote the answer here so it's easier for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating the zip file from scratch, use ZipOutputStream instead of ZipFile.  You can find an example of this in the [SharpZipLib sources](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx).  I'm not sure if ZipOutputStream supports adding to an existing zip file, so if that's what you're doing I'm afraid I don't have a useful answer.

Comment: Yea im trying to add to an existing zip file :-(