# Adding file to zip with SharpZipLib without creating temporary file

Tags: vb.net, sharpziplib

I am trying to add a file to an existing zip file using SharpZipLib. Preferably without creating any temporary files as the zip is large (about 2GB). And when using a temp file, the NTFS rights to the zip are changed. Not a good idea.

I tried the method supplied in the answer here [sharpziplib - can you add a file without it copying the entire zip first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987072/) like so:

```
Public Function AddManifestToZip(ByVal zipfilePath As String, ByVal manifestFilePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim zipArchive As SharpZip.ZipFile = New SharpZip.ZipFile(zipfilePath)
    If File.Exists(manifestFilePath) Then
        Dim diskarchivestorage = New DiskArchiveStorage(zipArchive, FileUpdateMode.Direct)
        zipArchive.BeginUpdate(diskarchivestorage)
        zipArchive.Add(manifestFilePath)
        zipArchive.CommitUpdate()
        zipArchive.Close()
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

However I get the following error from the .CommitUpdate(): "**Stream does not support writing**"

Anyone got any clues how to circumvent this?

Comment: "And when using a temp file, the NTFS rights to the zip are changed. Not a good idea"  The permissions should be correct for the folder and user. What's changing?

Comment: One or two users are removed from the access list. And the IIS_IUSRS had full access, but after the .commitupdate() only 'special permissions'

Comment: The file is probably inheriting the folder permissions, which are by default limited for folders in the web tree. If you save your files to a location that has the correct permissions, it should solve your problems.